# how to add a background that display "no data" on Canvas using ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I would like to add a background with text saying that there is no data available if it's the case, using ChartJS V2.9.3 .

For example, I would like to go from this (empty canva) :
[image: empty canvas]

To this (background color with text display) :

[image: no more empty background]

Do you have any suggestions for doing that ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Surely you can find out whether there's data available without using ChartJS and simply replace the canvas with an image? Or absolutely position the canvas on top of a div with text inside and simply hide the canvas? You don't have to solve this using ChartJS features.

Comment: Check the fiddle for sample implementation https://jsfiddle.net/x04ptfuu/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [global plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#global-plugins) that draws 'No data available' text in case no data is available.

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
  afterDraw: chart => {
    if (chart.data.datasets[0].data.length === 0) {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.font = "22px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
      ctx.fillText('No data available', chart.chart.width / 2, chart.chart.height / 2);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});

new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: []
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Works perflectly ! Thank you !

Comment: Glad I could help you.